# extract id number in cell of Google sheet

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have html code in cell C2

```
<b>Send my score to my teacher.</b>
<br><br>
<form class="login-form" action="send_results_processor.php?id=44623" method="post">
<table style="font-size: 14px;">
```

My full code in link: https://jsfiddle.net/bvotcode/z195augp/

My Google sheet (editable): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PX7VMX9QbC-RyIlp7EM3PpYCdbc_6EvYX6xPV18OXbw/edit?usp=sharing

How can extract id number, eg:44623 in above code and put it in cell C3

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B3,"id=(\d+)")
```